# How do I sort Dataset from the last 24 hours?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

| Temp | last_update |
| --- | --- |
| 35 | 06-21-2023 08:06:21 |
| 34 | 06-21-2023 08:06:21 |

My CSV File has over 100000 rows where data is collected since January 1. The last_update column is in date-time format. I have to make a dashboard. In the main page of the dashboard I want to show the temperature change in the last 24 hours. So if I wanna show the temperature at 8am on June 21, the graph should show the temperature change from June 20 8am until June 21 8am. Exactly 24 hours. That's the only problem I need help.

I tried tf = df['last_update'].last('24h') or df.last('24h') in order to create a new file called "TF" (as in Twenty Four) but I get the error ('last' only supports a DatetimeIndex index). The thing is my last_update is already in Date Time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`last('24h')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html) is not appropriate here because it returns only values from June 20 and not from June 20 8am until June 21 8am.

You can use [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) instead:

```
# If needed
df['last_update'] = pd.to_datetime(df['last_update'])

today = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize()
end = today + pd.DateOffset(hours=8)
start = end - pd.DateOffset(days=1)

out1 = df[df['last_update'].between(start, end)]
out2 = df.set_index('last_update').last('24h').reset_index()[df.columns]
```

Output:

```
# from June 20 8am to June 21 8am
>>> out1
       Temp         last_update
41944    25 2023-06-20 08:00:56
41945    22 2023-06-20 08:03:25
41946    29 2023-06-20 08:05:54
41947    25 2023-06-20 08:08:23
41948    20 2023-06-20 08:10:52
...     ...                 ...
42519    25 2023-06-21 07:48:51
42520    28 2023-06-21 07:51:20
42521    26 2023-06-21 07:53:49
42522    20 2023-06-21 07:56:18
42523    29 2023-06-21 07:58:47

# last 24h
>>> out2
     Temp         last_update
0      28 2023-06-21 00:01:59
1      27 2023-06-21 00:04:28
2      29 2023-06-21 00:06:57
3      27 2023-06-21 00:09:26
4      29 2023-06-21 00:11:55
..    ...                 ...
575    23 2023-06-21 23:49:54
576    24 2023-06-21 23:52:23
577    20 2023-06-21 23:54:52
578    27 2023-06-21 23:57:21
579    20 2023-06-21 23:59:50

[580 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have an integer **index** to your series df["last_update"] even if the values are datetimes.
In order to use the `last` method you need a datetime index.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last.html

Set your index to the "last_update" column using `set_index`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Temp": range(48),
        "last_update": pd.date_range("2018-04-09", periods=48, freq="1h"),
    }
)
df = df.set_index("last_update")
df.last("24h")
```